# How to do hold on in Rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have plotted a graph using rpy2. I am using Eclipse. When I run the code, the plot just blinks for 1 sec and go away. How do I make the graph to hold on? My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r = robjects.r

r('x = c(1, 2, 3)')
r('y = c(6, 7, 8)')

r('plot(x, y)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminating an R process closes interactive plotting windows left open... and this is what is happening at the end of your (Python) script.

If you have to keep your Python process alive (since the embedded R depends on it), there are several strategies. The simplest might be to add at the end:

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I am unable to close the R window. Everytime I run the program, it opens in new R windows which I am unable to close. Can you tell me, how do I close it?

Comment: Did you go through the documentation for making plots ? ( one entry point can be found in the introduction: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html#graphics-and-plots )

Answer (score 0):

You could use Rstudio, this does does kill the window instantly. Alternatively, dump the plot to file using e.g. `png`.

Comment: Dumping the plot to the file is a good idea! Thank you Paul..Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Start the program manually with `python your_program.py`. It must be a colateral from using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

grdevices = importr('grDevices')

def mainloop():
    while True:
        if isinstance(grdevices.dev_list(), type(robjects.NULL)):
            break

robjects.r('x = c(1, 2, 3)')
robjects.r('y = c(6, 7, 8)')

robjects.r('plot(x, y)')
mainloop()
```

Comment: Please use Blocking to keep your Python process.